# Flexbox with fixed width elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

I have a pyramid shape of images contained in a Flexbox. It works as expected as long as the width of the images is fixed. If I resize the screen (or change it to a smaller resolution), since it's a Flexbox, the base items (lower row) will have less space and will be shrinked.

I would ideally like to have a dynamic base size for base items (the smaller the screen is, the smaller the items will be), but the items sizes on the rows above should be indexed on the lower row and have the same size.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve: https://codepen.io/Mantequilla_/pen/WNrWBWW
Once the browser is resized (or the resolution too low), the pyramid is malformed (e.g. the upper an item is, the bigger it will be which is unwanted).

Not sure, what I want to achieve is doable in CSS only but I'm open to any suggestions.

Example code for reference:

```css
.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img class="Pyramide-img-128" src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img class="Pyramide-img-128" src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img class="Pyramide-img-128" src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img class="Pyramide-img-128" src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img class="Pyramide-img-128" src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img class="Pyramide-img-128" src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img class="Pyramide-img-128" src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img class="Pyramide-img-128" src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img class="Pyramide-img-128" src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img class="Pyramide-img-128" src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a view width.

```
 <style>
    .row {
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .item {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    img {
       width: 5vw;
       margin-left: 2.5vw;
       margin-right: 2.5vw;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Will have a look into vw a bit more.

Comment: Awesome to hear! https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp, https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/ happy coding!

Comment: @JeffreyMuller you should consider the fact that the cards can be very big on bigger screen.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of row is known or you have a maximum value you can try like below:

```css
:root {
  --r:5; /* number of row */
}
body {
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
}
.container {
  display:inline-flex;  
  flex-direction:column;
}
.row {
  padding:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: flex;
  list-style:none;
}
img {
  width: 50%;
}

.row:not(:last-child) {
  width:0;
}

/* you can easily generate the below using SASS/LESS*/
.row:nth-last-child(2) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 1)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(3) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 2)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(4) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 3)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(5) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 4)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(6) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 5)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(7) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 6)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(8) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 7)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(9) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 8)/var(--r));}
/*.row:nth-last-child(N) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - (N-1))/var(--r));}*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

With more rows:

```css
:root {
  --r:7; /* number of row */
}
body {
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
}
.container {
  display:inline-flex;  
  flex-direction:column;
}
.row {
  padding:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: flex;
  list-style:none;
}
img {
  width: 50%;
}

.row:not(:last-child) {
  width:0;
}

/* you can easily generate the below using SASS/LESS*/
.row:nth-last-child(2) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 1)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(3) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 2)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(4) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 3)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(5) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 4)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(6) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 5)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(7) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 6)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(8) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 7)/var(--r));}
.row:nth-last-child(9) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - 8)/var(--r));}
/*.row:nth-last-child(N) {min-width:calc(100% * (var(--r) - (N-1))/var(--r));}*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8ZYUZbG.png" alt="Card"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```